# coda question on javascript

Tags: javascript, coda

I have a quick question on Coda. Not sure if this for this website but i'm sure someone here will tell me. Does Coda have javascript error recognition like dreamweaver does or is there a plug-in for it. I keep having to switch dreamweaver to test stuff and I'd really like to stop doing that.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Coda's 'preview' mode uses Webkit, and therefore has essentially the same Javascript debugging and error recognition capabilities as Chrome's and Safari's Developer Tools.

In Coda, go to Preview mode. Right click, and 'inspect element'. Then, click on the Scripts panel. You should be able to find what you need there.